# How to generate an attribute according to a condition using executescript in apache nifi (jython)?

Tags: apache-nifi

I am using apache nifi to store logs in kafka.

I have some lines of log, that depending on the content I have to send them to a topic kafka or other. 
The problem I have is that there are many topics and therefore I would have to use many processors.

I have thought that using 'executescript', I could, according to the conditions I have in the logs text, generate a dynamic attribute that I can use in the 'topic name' property of the publishkafka processor.

I started with the code to read the content of the flowfile, as well as to write some of the conditions, but I don't know how to generate the attribute.

Some examples of the log lines:
Jim,18,M,156,Oregon,USA,etc
John,55,M,170,Idaho,USA,etc

Here's what I have so far:

```
from org.apache.commons.io import IOUtils
from java.nio.charset import StandardCharsets
from org.apache.nifi.processor.io import StreamCallback

class PyStreamCallback(StreamCallback):
    def __init__(self):
         pass
    def process(self, inputStream, outputStream):
         Log = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
         TextLog = str(Log).split(',')
         name = TextLog[0]
         age = TextLog[1]
         sex = TextLog[2]

         if name == 'John' and age == '30':
             Topic_A = str(TextLog) 
             outputStream.write(bytearray((Topic_A).encode('utf-8')))
         elif name == 'Max' and age == '25':
             Topic_B = str(TextLog)
             outputStream.write(bytearray((Topic_B).encode('utf-8')))
         elif name == 'Smith' and age == '10' or '20':
             Topic_C = str(TextLog)
             outputStream.write(bytearray((Topic_C).encode('utf-8')))
```

The goal is to have a single executescript processor and a single kafka processor.
Please, someone can help me.

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is:

```
flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, 'my-property', 'my-value')
```

https://funnifi.blogspot.com/2016/02/executescript-processor-hello-world.html

A typical way this would be done without writing any custom code, is to use RouteOnContent...

You can add a user-defined properties where the name will become a relationship and the value is a regular expression.

For example, adding two properties:

```
john = John,30,.*
max = Max,25,.*
```

From there you would send each relationship to an UpdateAttribute processor where you set the topic name, so john would go to an UpdateAttribute that set topic = Topic_A and max would go to an UpdateAttribute that set topic = Topic_B.

Then they would all connect to a single PublishKafka where the topic was set to ${topic}.

Comment: hello brian, because I have a lot of kafka topics, to avoid having dozens of processors in the flow, I try to do it with executescript. because I have many kafka topics and if I use routeoncontent and then updateattribute. Although I will only have one publishkafka, but I will have many updateattribute.Thanks for the help, I'll try to clarify myself on putattribute as you comment.

Comment: Brian, if I understand correctly, what I would have to do is this?                `if name == 'John' and age == '30':
             Topic_A = str(TextLog) 
             outputStream.write(bytearray((Topic_A).encode('utf-8')))
             flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, 'my-property', 'Topic_A')`

Comment: you don't want to write to the outputStream because then you'd be overwriting the content of the flow file, you want to read in the content using an input stream callback and then set the attribute appropriately

Comment: Actually, I was planning to take advantage of it and remove some fields. That's why outputStream.write. What I'm not clear is if in the same script, I can open the flowfile content, according to certain conditions, generate an attribute, remove some field from the flowfile content and finally have the flowfile output already modified with the corresponding attribute according to its content.

Comment: you can't add an attribute within a callback, take a look at this example where the first the content is written, then after the write callback is done, then an attribute is added https://funnifi.blogspot.com/2016/02/executescript-processor-replacing-flow.html